# Check internet connectivity in mobile application using phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

On creating the mobile app in phonegap, I would like to show an alert message regarding internet connectivity as online / offline. But I do not get the alert message. I used

> cordova-plugin-network-information

plugin with the code below on my js file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]); </script>
```

Can any one help me with the solution?

Answer (score 1):

First Add the below Cordova Plugins:

> [cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/index.html#network-related-events)
>
> [cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/index.html)

Add Below cript files:

> jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css
>     jquery-1.10.2.min.js
>     cordova.js

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" name="viewport"
            content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" />
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">

</script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
                document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
                document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
                function onDeviceReady() {
                    console.log(" ready");
                }

                function onOnline() {
                    console.log("connected");
                }

                function onOffline() {
                    debugger;
                    console.log("lost connection");

                    navigator.notification.alert(
                        'Please Check your internet connection.', // message
                        null, // callback
                        'Sample', // title
                        'OK' // buttonName
                    );
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="top:100px;"> Sample</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Output:**
[image: Output]
For More Details Click [Here..!](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/index.html#network-related-events)

Comment: I tried the above code, but it is also not working. It does not show any of the alert message

Comment: I added the above code, but it didn't work. It does not show any message while the user is offline

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that document has loaded before adding the above code. Do something like this in your HTML:

```
<body onload="onLoad">
```

and in your script/JS file do something like this:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
   //call your internet connectivity code here...
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code, but it is not working. It does not show any of the alert message